# in Postgres 9.5, can you select a set of users and have a subset be ordered first?

Tags: postgresql

We have a list of users but would like the subset of users who are friends to be first if they exist and sorted in a specific order. Let's say your friend_user_ids are [6,4,2] (such that if user 2 and 6 were retuned, they would be sorted as 6 first and 2 second.

Would it be possible to say:

```
select * from users where is_valid=true order by friend_user_ids ....
```

Comment: try to improve your question by adding some table schema. how would you select the friends? something like who is friend of this user?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Turn the position in the friend array into a priority and order on that:

```
select * from users where is_valid=true
order by array_position(ARRAY[6,4,2],friend_user_ids)
```